# search missing values in object array

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array that I bind to a javascript based pivot table. The data is missing some of the require rows. So, I need to find which data may be missing and inject it in my object array.

The data is in the format:
**Person, WorkType, month, value**
Me, Baseline, 10, 12.00
Me, Planned, 10, 12.00
Me, Actual, 10, 6.00
You, Planned, 10, 12.00

I am pivoting rows on the person and type columns. However as you see here Person "You" does not have at least one record for Baseline or Actual and I need to figure out which data is missing and inject at least one row for the missing work type so my pivot view is uniform.

Any good idea's how to evaluate my object array and inject the missing row(s)?

kb

Comment: Maybe I don't understand whats happening but the `Baseline` & `Actual` data. Where Is that exactly? All I see and expect is person "You" should have `Person, type, month, value` "schema". Maybe you should be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought I was being precise and keeping this strictly a javascript array question but realize I wasn't very clear. I also updated type to be "work type" for clarity. There is no baseline and actual data for some people. And to be precise, in a javascript array what is an efficient method to find/search "for each distinct person", one of each type of work, baseline, planned, and actual? I found many example of comparing object arrays but those don't seem to hold water in this scenario. Or, I just don't understand how to search against two properties simultaneously.

Comment: I suppose a more concise example would be something more like a sql query  "where Person = "You" AND WorkType = "Actual". How can I perform this against a javascript object array?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with. Though I think it lacks efficiency.

```
var table = $('#GridView1').tableToJSON(); // Convert the table into a javascript object

    var personArray = []; // object instead of array
    $.each(table, function(i, item){
        if($.inArray(item.Person, personArray) == -1)personArray.push(item.Person);
    });

    var foundWorktypes = [];
    var wtypes = ["Actual", "BaselinePlanned", "Planned"]

    //for each distinct person
    $.each(personArray, function(i, person){
        //for each work type
        $.each(wtypes, function(i, wtype){
            //for each record
            $.each(table, function(i, record){
                if(record.Person== person && record.WType == wtype) foundWorktypes.push(wtype);
                if(foundWorktypes.length == 3) return;
            });
            if(foundWorktypes.length == 3) return;
        });

        //now check for each work type if it is missing in the distinct persons work tyes
        $.each(wtypes, function(i, wtype2){
            if($.inArray(wtype2, foundWorktypes) <= -1) table.push({Person: person, MonthNr: 10, YearNr: 2099, WType: wtype2, Hours: 0});           
        });
        //clear the array for the next person
        foundWorktypes = [];
    });
```